# What is the best way to store highly parametrized entities?

Tags: sql, mongodb, database-design, database, nosql

Ok, let met try to explain this in more detail.
I am developing a diagnostic system for airplanes. Let imagine that airplanes has 6 to 8 on-board computers. Each computer has more than 200 different parameters. The diagnostic system receives all this parameters in binary formatted package, then I transfer data according to the formulas (to km, km/h, rpm, min, sec, pascals and so on) and must store it somehow in a database. The new data must be handled each 10 - 20 seconds and stored in persistence again.
We store the data for further analytic processing.

**Requirements of storage**:

- support sharding and replication
- fast read: support btree-indexing
- NOSQL
- fast write

So, I calculated an average disk or RAM usage per one plane per day. It is about 10 - 20 MB of data. So an estimated load is 100 airplanes per day or 2GB of data per day.

It seems that to store all the data in RAM (memcached-liked storages: redis, membase) are not suitable (too expensive). However, now I am looking to the mongodb-side. Since it can utilize as RAM and disk usage, it supports all the addressed requirements.

Please, share your experience and advices.

Comment: What sort of tools do you want to use to analyze the data? If OLAP, then want a traditional SQL interface. Could use Hive against HBase or Hadoop. Need map-reduce against mongo.

Comment: Thank you @NeilMcGuigan for your contribution. For analytics I would like pre-aggregated data to be processed with [storm](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm) (java-based). Since it easily distributed and guarantees availability. What do you think ? Could you be more specific, please! I need more details, may be use cases that you already covered.

Comment: How long do you need to store the data for (since analyzing real-time)?

Do you need random-access read ability?

You might be fine just putting the data in HDFS (Hadoop File System).

Comment: Good question. Yeah I have a thought about it (I checked Facebook Scribe solution). However, we also have web portal, where special people can read original data (not analyzed). There are a lot of read operations required.

Answer (score 1):

There is a helpful article on [NOSQL DBMS Comparison.](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis)
Also you may find [information about the ranking and popularity](http://db-engines.com/en/ranking) of them, by category.
It seems regarding to your requirements, [Apache's Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) would be a candidate due to its  Linear scalability, column indexes, Map/reduce, materialized views and powerful built-in caching.